# Typed property App\Http\Livewire\Roles\EditUserRole::$user_model must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: laravel-livewire

// Throw an Error While I have Already Initialized? Please need Help

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->user_model = new User();

    $this->userData = $this->user_model->displayUsers();

    $this->role_model = $role_model ?? new Role();

    $this->roleData = $this->role_model->displayRoles();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set default values in your property definitions.

```
class YouLivewireClass extends Component
{
    public string $email = "";
    public int $number = 0;
    public ?User $user = null;

    public function mount()
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

`mount()` method in Livewire is not the same as a `__construct` method.

It is called very early but the object is already created and some of the general PHP checks are executed. If you define strict types for the properties that can result in error in Livewire, because they can not fallback to null for the initialisation process.

Here a nice explanation from the Livewire forum: https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/1-0-3-typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initialization/320

> For anyone wondering why: With the typed properties in 7.4 they have a
> state of initialized and uninitialized, instead of the expected
> behavior of properties defaulting to a null value if there isn’t one
> assigned. In “regular” classes, the properties can maintain an
> uninitialized state, and this error is only thrown when you try to
> actually access it. Which all makes sense because the point of it all
> is to have stricter code.
>
> There’s a few reasons why Livewire (and a portion of Laravel for that
> matter) is different than a textbook oop object. First, mount() should
> not be thought of as __construct(), and should be thought of closer to
> Laravel’s boot() method. The object has been built already, and some
> behind the scenes work has been done that makes Livewire work, before
> the mount() method is called. mount() is just the first method called
> in in the code you provide to Livewire.